# How to get a bean real class instead CGlib proxy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "core.organizations")
public class PermissionConfig {
...
}
```

I want to get its real class. If I get it by method `bean.getClass()`, I will get CGlib proxy instead.

I have tried using `AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean)`, `AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(bean)`, but it returns same proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#getUserClass-java.lang.Object-

You can use ClassUtils.getUserClass(Object bean) to get parent class of the CGLIB-generated subclass.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [spring github ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20132)

The `AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean)` does not work with beans annotated as `@Configuration`. I have used `ClassUtils.getUserClass(bean)` for my bean. It worked

Comment: I was too slow! Just posted... the same thing.